# When adding WatchKit target, I get No Assistant Results on main scene

Tags: storyboard, watchkit, xcode7, iboutlet

I am trying to add a new WatckKit target to an old project. Yet when I do it and immediately trigger the Assistant Editor, and click the initial controller, no file is loaded and message "No Assistant Result" is shown. Of course if I manually select the file, then connecting the outlet produces errors. I tried deleting and reinserting the target several times, as well clear the derived folder, restart Xcode and also the Mac, but the situation remains the same.
When I did the same thing on new project following some tutorials, I never had this problems. What might it be and how to fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact I forgot to assign the module in the WatchKit scene. Now the Assistant Editor plugs in seamlessly.